# ConstraintViolationException in Java RESTful Webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I'm relatively new to JavaEE and web services, however, I'm using netbeans to generate my client and webservice resources. I have a resource "CustomerData" that represents a mysql database table and a value "rewardsPoints" representing a column in that table, however, I am unable to update the value due to a ConstraintViolationException, specifically:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'preUpdate'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
```

I'm not familiar with the 'preUpdate' callback event, is it something I need to override? I can't seem to figure out exactly why this exception is being thrown, but, as I said, i'm very new to web service programming. Here are my classes:

```
@Stateless
@Path("customers")
public class CustomerDataFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<CustomerData> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CustomerPortalPU")
    private EntityManager em;
    public CustomerDataFacadeREST() {
        super(CustomerData.class);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, CustomerData entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public CustomerData find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }
    @GET
    @Path("addPoints/{id}/{amount}")
    @Produces({"text/plain"})
    public String addPoints(@PathParam("id") Integer id, @PathParam("amount") int amount) {
        CustomerData customer = find(id);
    customer.getRewardsPoints(customer.getRewardsPoints() + amount);
    em.persist(customer);
    edit(customer);
    return customer.getRewardsPoints();
    }
    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

And the CustomerData entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_customer_data")
@XmlRootElement
public class CustomerData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "rewards_points")
    private int rewardsPoints;
    public CustomerData(Integer id, int rewardsPoints) {
        this.id = id;
        this.rewardsPoints = rewardsPoints;
    }   
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getRewardsPoints() {
        return rewardsPoints;
    }
    public void setRewardsPoints(int rewardsPoints) {
        this.rewardsPoints = rewardsPoints;
    }
}
```

When I try to access the URI:

```
http://localhost:8080/CustomerPortal/ws/customers/addPoints/1/5
```

to add 5 points to user with id 1 i get an HTTP 500 error and in the glassfish logs it says

```
[2013-11-05T03:28:11.733-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [ejb.system_exception] [javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1383640091733] [levelValue: 900] [[
  EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB CustomerDataFacadeREST, method: public java.lang.String com.webservice.entities.CustomerDataFacadeREST.addPoints(java.lang.Integer,int)]]

[2013-11-05T03:28:11.741-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1383640091741] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[com.webservice.entities.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.webservice.entities.ApplicationConfig threw exception
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'preUpdate'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
```

Any resources, insight or information regarding this issue would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The exception has little to do with web services: it has to do with [Bean Validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partbeanvalidation.htm#sthref1322) instead.

In this case, since the Validation fails inside method `addPoints` (look at the stack trace) the only line that can cause it is when persisting or editing an Entity of type `CustomerData`. The only constraint you have in that class is that `rewardsPoints` should not be null. So, that's the cause of the exception.

However there some things that won't work in `addPoints` method:

- You should check that find() method doesn't return a null object.
- `customer.getRewardsPoints(customer.getRewardsPoints() + amount)` never sets the property (does it compile?)
- [`EntityManager.persist()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist%28java.lang.Object%29) throws exception if the entity already exists. You probably want to remove that line if you only want to edit (update) the entity.

Note: I am not sure that the code you have posted is really compiling and causing that exception. That's probably caused by another version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so i tried to shorten the code to make it easier to read because there are other methods that are irrelevant to my question, but I shuold have included that what I do first is apply the customer.getRewardsPoints() to a variable, currentPoints, then create a variable that adds currentPoints to the method argument (int total = currentPoints+amount), then customer.setRewardsPoints(total);
it compiles fine, I will try removing the @NotNull constraint and see whats going on. thank you for your input!